# Comparing weights between significant predictors in GLM with binomial outcome

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model

I need to compare the explanatory power of several predictor variables $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\} \in \mathbb{R}$ for a response variable $y$. For this problem, we can use logistic regression as a generalized linear model:

$$logit(p_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1,i + \beta_2 x_2,i + \beta_3 x_3,i + \beta_4 x_4,i$$

$\forall i \in [1,N]$, where $N$ is the number of observations.

Any statistical software can fit the model and provide weights and p-values for each predictor in the model. What is the **simplest** method to compare the resulting weights that are significant? From my reading, it appears one method of making the weights comparable in standard GLM approaches is to scale $\beta_j$ by the standard deviation of the predictor variable:

$$\beta_j' = \beta_j \sigma_j$$

However, is this approach still valid for a GLM with binomial response variable? If not, is there another straightforward way to do this?

Comment: The simplest method to assess the importance of the different predictors is to look at the p-values. Small means important. Can you explain in your question why or why not the p-values already serve your purpose? What else are you after?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - my question was meant to focus on the set of _significant_ predictors and comparing between these. I'll edit accordingly now.

Comment: The edits don't help. You've missed my point, which was to examine the size of the p-values, not just apply preset significant cutoff. I will write an answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the $\beta'_j$ measure you propose doesn't have a useful role in understanding logistic regression and you would be better of using traditional generalized linear model summaries.

Here is a simple logistic regression example to show that the $\beta_j'$ measures are misleading:

```
> x1 <- seq(from=-1, to=1, length=1000)
> beta <- 0.5
> p <- exp(x1*beta) / (1+exp(x1*beta))
> y <- rbinom(1000, prob=p, size=1)
> x2 <- rep(0,1000)
> x2[500] <- 1
> y[500] <- 1
> fit <- glm(y~x1+x2, family=binomial, maxit=100, epsilon=1e-18)
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

In this example x1 is highly significant whereas x2 is not significant at all.
x2 has little or no predictive power:
We can see this either from the t-statistics and Wald p-values:

```
> summary(fit)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial, maxit = 100, epsilon = 1e-18)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.4218  -1.1601   0.9551   1.1401   1.3907  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 3.481e-02  6.400e-02   0.544    0.587    
x1          5.234e-01  1.117e-01   4.686 2.78e-06 ***
x2          3.153e+01  6.711e+07   0.000    1.000    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1386.0  on 999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1362.2  on 997  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1368.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 30
```

or from analysis of deviance and likelihood ratio tests:

```
> anova(fit, test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: y

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


     Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                   999     1386.0              
x1    1  22.4111       998     1363.6 2.201e-06 ***
x2    1   1.3513       997     1362.2     0.245    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Nevertheless x2 has a much higher $\beta_j'$ measure than x1:

```
> beta1 <- coef(fit)[2]
> beta2 <- coef(fit)[3]
> beta1*sd(x1)
[1] 0.3026638
> beta2*sd(x2)
[1] 0.9971314
```

Here the value of $\beta_2'$ would actually be infinite if we were able to fit the glm in exact arithmetic rather than on a floating point computer.

Measuring predictive power in a meaningful way requires comparing the predicted probabilities to the actual outcome values.
One useful summary is the area under the receiver operating curve (auROC):

The fitted model with x1 has auROC of 59%, regardless of whether x2 is in the model as well:

```
> library(limma)
> auROC(y, fitted(fit))
[1] 0.5870262
> fit1 <- glm(y~x1, family=binomial)
> auROC(y,fitted(fit1))
[1] 0.5861539
```

x2 alone is hardly better than random:

```
> fit2 <- glm(y~x2, family=binomial)
> auROC(y, fitted(fit2))
[1] 0.5009823
```